# Events from database show to google calendar

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, google-calendar-api

I am developing an app, which works like a booking system. The main-component is a calendar which shows created events, which are stored in PostgreSQL database. My challenge now, is to show all the events from database to the admin´s google calendar. When the admin opens his google calendar, he only has rights to see the events, but not to edit them.

The technologies i am using is Apache/Tomcat, Java, Spring and Hibernate.
Can someone help me, or guide me to some clear solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for guide, then the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events) can help you a lot.

First thing, you need to understand the concept of Google Calendar API. You can read the [basic concept on the overview page](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/#basic_concepts) for further details. Moreover, if your aim is just more on the events, then you will need to make sure that you have visited [this](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/events-calendars#events).

Here is a sample snippet all the way from the sample given in the documentation. This sample demonstrate creating an event and setting its metadata:

> ```
> // Refer to the Java quickstart on how to setup the environment:
> // https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java
> // Change the scope to CalendarScopes.CALENDAR and delete any stored
> // credentials.
>
> Event event = new Event()
>     .setSummary("Google I/O 2015")
>     .setLocation("800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103")
>     .setDescription("A chance to hear more about Google's developer products.");
>
> DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime("2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00");
> EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
>     .setDateTime(startDateTime)
>     .setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
> event.setStart(start);
>
> DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime("2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00");
> EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
>     .setDateTime(endDateTime)
>     .setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
> event.setEnd(end);
>
> String[] recurrence = new String[] {"RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2"};
> event.setRecurrence(Arrays.asList(recurrence));
>
> EventAttendee[] attendees = new EventAttendee[] {
>     new EventAttendee().setEmail("lpage@example.com"),
>     new EventAttendee().setEmail("sbrin@example.com"),
> };
> event.setAttendees(Arrays.asList(attendees));
>
> EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
>     new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(24 * 60),
>     new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10),
> };
> Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
>     .setUseDefault(false)
>     .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
> event.setReminders(reminders);
>
> String calendarId = "primary";
> event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
> System.out.printf("Event created: %s\n", event.getHtmlLink());
> ```